# Split rows into multiple rows based on quantity

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a rows in my table:

```
 id  m_id quantity
 1   1  1500
 2   1  -1000
 3   2  -3000
 4   2   2000
 5   3  400
 6   3  -1000
 7   4   500
 8   4   -500
 9   5   1500
```

I want to create a view that will return this:

```
 id   m_id   quantity
  1  1    500
  2  1    1000
  3   1    -1000
  4   2   -1000
  5   2   -2000
  6   2   2000
  7   3   400
  8   3   -400
  9   3   -600
  10  4   500
  11  4   -500
  12  5   1500
```

View will return equal values in positive/negative and split the rest in a separate rows. So two rows are separated into three rows if positive and negative numbers differ for a given `m_id`.

Comment: When there is not any unique column in your sample data that you can specify next row, there is no any guarantee for achieving that result ;).

Comment: ah I have given a short form of the problem. there is a primary key on the table. modified the sample data

Comment: For every value of 'id' you always have 1 or 2 rows, never more?

Comment: Yes Patrick for each 'm_id' maximum of two rows. There can be one row only as 'm_id' 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT *, 
        LAG(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY m_id ORDER BY id) as pq, -- Previous quantity based on id
        LEAD(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY m_id ORDER BY id) as nq -- Next quantity based on id
    FROM yourTable    
), t2 AS (
SELECT id, m_id, 1 as ord,
    CASE 
        -- If sign is changed and quantity is bigger than that use next quantity
        WHEN (SIGN(nq) <> SIGN(quantity)) AND (ABS(quantity) > ABS(nq)) THEN -nq
        -- If sign is changed and quantity is bigger than that use previous quantity
        WHEN (SIGN(pq) <> SIGN(quantity)) AND (ABS(quantity) > ABS(pq)) THEN -pq
        -- Else use original quantity
        ELSE quantity
    END As quantity
FROM t1
UNION ALL  -- Add extra rows
SELECT id , m_id,
    CASE 
        -- Set order to be higher than original quantity
        WHEN (SIGN(nq) <> SIGN(quantity)) AND (ABS(quantity) > ABS(nq)) THEN 0
        -- Set order to be lower than original quantity
        WHEN (SIGN(pq) <> SIGN(quantity)) AND (ABS(quantity) > ABS(pq)) THEN 2
    END As ord,
    -- quantity is difference
    CASE 
        WHEN (SIGN(nq) <> SIGN(quantity)) AND (ABS(quantity) > ABS(nq)) THEN nq + quantity
        WHEN (SIGN(pq) <> SIGN(quantity)) AND (ABS(quantity) > ABS(pq)) THEN pq + quantity
    END As quantity
FROM t1
WHERE   
    -- Find differences more
    1 = CASE 
            WHEN (SIGN(nq) <> SIGN(quantity)) AND (ABS(quantity) > ABS(nq)) THEN 1
            WHEN (SIGN(pq) <> SIGN(quantity)) AND (ABS(quantity) > ABS(pq)) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END)
SELECT 
    -- Use new values for id
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id, ord) As id, 
    m_id, quantity
FROM t2;
```

Comment: but i must say it will take a lot of time for me to understand how this is working....

Comment: I add some description ;).